# Taking apart wood bed frame with no screws

Tags: bedroom

This bedframe seems to have a slot joint system but I can't seem to understand how to take it apart. There are two pegs I think will allow me to slide the side out but I'm not sure how to get the pegs out.[image: img1]

Comment: Have you tried just lifting? Or depending how much it's been painted, hitting in a direction opposed to gravity? The extended slot below indicates a likely "no need to remove bolts" disassembly by lifting the rail and then moving the head/foot away from the rail.

Comment: ...also...  were you the person who cut the slots into the pegs? Telling us these things without making us guess is helpful in getting to an answer that works faster...

Comment: Looks to me that staples were being used to hold in those metal (?) plugs when the bed was painted and then the staples were removed at some point.

Comment: I removed the staples holding the pegs in. I tried lifting before I posted but after everyone here suggested just lifting, I tried the other side and it worked! It looks like the side I was working on it stuck so I'll have to try to take a mallet to it or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the board just slides upward.  See the slot underneath the board?  Lift up on the board with the pegs, and gently tap the board with the slot downward using a hammer or something.  The board with the pegs probably has some J hooks that slide into the slot and hook over a peg, dowel, or whatever that crosses through the slot.

Edit:  Here's a picture likely resembling what you have that goes into that slot.

[image]

Comment: I just noticed... see the round circles in the post?  Those are the pegs that the J hooks "lock" onto after being inserted into the slots and then lowered down.

Comment: I couldn't remove the pegs, but I tried the other side and it did lift up!! SO the side I was working on was stuck. I guess I'll have to take a mallet to it.

Answer (score 0):

My expensive wooden bed frame has what looks like the same things. If so, they are plugs that have to be removed to access the screws behind those plugs holding the bed together. Just take a very small screw driver and try to remove those plugs.